# Compiling boost 1.53 libraries with gcc with symbol visibility hidden

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, ld

I'm getting some annoying errors from my linker:

ld:  warning: direct access in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::sp_counted_base() to global weak symbol vtable for boost::detail::sp_counted_base means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.

After rooting around, I've determined that this is caused by compiling with -fvisibility=hidden, which is what I need. So I need to compile boost with hidden symbols and all should be good, right?

I noted that, when building boost with ./b2, it lists the following near the top of the output:

Performing configuration checks

```
- gcc visibility           : yes
```

Great, but how can I turn visibility off? The documentation doesn't seem to mention it. I tried passing "-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fvisibility=hidden" directly to the compiler, but this doesn't work (for some reason).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I compile with `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden` and stock Boost 1.53 links fine. I'm wondering which library you're using? (E.g. Boost.Exceptions had some issues in previous versions.)

Comment: Hi, my problem is with boost_regex.